# Access error on wamp

Tags: php, zend-framework, wamp

Trying to configure Zend into Wamp Server, but the only answer i have is:

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /blandit/public on this server.

Is there any guide that i can follow to configure it?

Comment: Made sure to check the admin/user permission settings on /blandit folder?

Answer (score 0):

Check you have mod_rewrite enabled in apache and a valid .htaccess file in your public folder.

It sounds like you might have directory listing disabled and it's not routing through index.php if it's not a permissions problem.

Check your apache error log for clues
Here's a screencast that might help. http://www.zendcasts.com/getting-started-with-zend-and-wamp-server/2009/06/